# Page load captcha not load in webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, reload

I am using webbrowser into Windows application.
When webbrowser navigate first time, there is no problem.
But calling second time webbrowser navigate captcha does not change.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("uyg.sgk.gov.tr/SgkTescil4a");
    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
}
```

Comment: Post some code and identify exactly what the problem is. From the very little you have given in your question I suspect the problem is in the webbrowser control caching the page content.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://uyg.sgk.gov.tr/SgkTescil4a");
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
        }

Comment: this is my code.. it is simple but click button captcha not change

Answer (score 0):

To prevent page caching on your client, which may be the reason why you see the Captcha not changing use

webbrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely).

to clear the cache. If its not a client side caching issue, then its a problem with the website.